# Parsing through JSON Dict of Dicts or List of Dicts? (Python)

Tags: python, json, list

I'm having trouble understanding whether this is a dict of dicts or a list of dicts and also how do I access keys and their corresponding values such as: 'volatility' = 29.0 or 'ask' = 11.61?

```
{
    "symbol": "SPY",
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "underlying": None,
    "strategy": "SINGLE",
    "interval": 0.0,
    "isDelayed": False,
    "isIndex": False,
    "interestRate": 0.1,
    "underlyingPrice": 378.28499999999997,
    "volatility": 29.0,
    "daysToExpiration": 0.0,
    "numberOfContracts": 1,
    "putExpDateMap": {
        "2021-01-22:7": {
            "390.0": [
                {
                    "putCall": "PUT",
                    "symbol": "SPY_012221P390",
                    "description": "SPY Jan 22 2021 " "390 Put " "(Weekly)",
                    "exchangeName": "OPR",
                    "bid": 11.46,
                    "ask": 11.61,
                    "last": 11.84,
                    "mark": 11.55,
                    "bidSize": 50,
                    "askSize": 50,
                    "bidAskSize": "50X50",
                    "lastSize": 0,
                    "highPrice": 11.89,
                    "lowPrice": 9.38,
                    "openPrice": 0.0,
                    "closePrice": 10.27,
                    "totalVolume": 461,
                    "tradeDate": None,
                    "tradeTimeInLong": 1610658217962,
                    "quoteTimeInLong": 1610658899875,
                    "netChange": 1.57,
                    "volatility": 13.012,
                    "delta": -0.945,
                    "gamma": 0.02,
                    "theta": -0.035,
                    "vega": 0.062,
                    "rho": -0.035,
                    "openInterest": 207,
                    "timeValue": 0.3,
                    "theoreticalOptionValue": 11.628,
                    "theoreticalVolatility": 29.0,
                    "optionDeliverablesList": None,
                    "strikePrice": 390.0,
                    "expirationDate": 1611349200000,
                    "daysToExpiration": 7,
                    "expirationType": "S",
                    "lastTradingDay": 1611363600000,
                    "multiplier": 100.0,
                    "settlementType": " ",
                    "deliverableNote": "",
                    "isIndexOption": None,
                    "percentChange": 15.29,
                    "markChange": 1.28,
                    "markPercentChange": 12.47,
                    "nonStandard": False,
                    "inTheMoney": True,
                    "mini": False,
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "callExpDateMap": {},
}
```

So here's the error I keep getting whenever I try to print out print(jsonDict['volatility'].json()):
Hope this helps.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/casseroleRow/Desktop/Learning/Learning.gyp", line 26, in <module>
    print(jsonDict['volatility'].json())
TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: This is a nested structured composed of both dicts & lists. Accessing the keys & values depends on which level they are located. for example, `volatility` is at the top level so it can be accessed with `d['volatility']`. While `ask` is deeply nested so needs to be accessed with `d['putExpDateMap']['2021-01-22:7']['390.0'][0]['ask']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you will have to parse it like this:

```
jsonDict.json()['volatility'] or jsonDict.json()['putExpDateMap'].json()['2021-01-22:7'].json()['390.0'][0].json()['ask']
```

Comment: Yep here's what I got: 'jsonDict' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @KamHaliloff You have to name the json object jsonDict or maybe change jsonDict to whatever name you want

Comment: I did name it jsonDict ma dude but still got nothing.

Comment: Okay can you please attach error in your question

Comment: Attached it! Please check

Comment: why do you attach .json() at the end?, Use it without that.

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry man still learning haha. Let me redact the question one more time.

Comment: You should do: `jsonDict.json()['volatility']`

Comment: `jsonDict` is a `Response` object. Using `.json()` on it gives you the body as a dictionary. Then you can use the access methods specified in the answer.

Comment: Ma guys you are lifesavers! I'm still learning how to parse Json code so excuse my questions haha. Can't thank you enough!!